# call not displaying the name of the function

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb

I've been trying to crack my own programs lately but I'm having a problem with gdb. Gdb afaik should be displaying something like

```
call    0x100000f2c <printf@plt>
```

but instead my gdb would display

```
call    0x100000f2c
```

without showing what the function is. I'm compiling the programs with

```
gcc -g license_1.c -o license_1
```

Is there any way around this or does the osx gdb just have less features?

Comment: Did you compile your programs with `-g` option ?

Comment: this is how I'm compiling them gcc -g license_1.c -o license_1

Comment: Did you get it working?